# WPF Binding INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a theoretical problem.

```
<ListBox ItemSource= "{Binding Fruits}" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" />
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox
```

Let's assume I have `ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits` in my ViewModel.
Fruit is not my class so I can't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` when Fruit Color changes.
I know in my ViewModel when these properties are changed for example:

```
public ChangeColor()
{
Fruits[1].Color = "Blue";
//Notify Fruits Here, How?
}
```

1. How to do that?
2. How it works when implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` behind the scenes? If I have `ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits` and Fruit Color property changes it is sent something like `NotifyPropertyChanged("Fruits.Name")` ?

Comment: wrap your `Fruit` in an `FruitViewModel` that encapsulates the Fruit and adds the INotifyPropertyChanged-Functionality, to raise the PropertyChangedEvent when Color is changed

Comment: Alternatively you can look at Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) just google POSTSHARP. It's much longer way then wrapping your M in VM as per the suggestion above.

Comment: Okay that's right. But what about second question ? How to update Every Color in ItemsSource by Invoking Event in ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

1. By "Fruit is not my class", you mean that the class Fruit is written by someone else or encapsulated into some dll? If so, you may still subclass Fruit and implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, something like:

   ```
   public class FruitsEx : Fruits, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public Color ColorEx
       {
           get { return this.Color; }
           set
           {
               this.Color = value;

               if (PropertyChanged != null)
               {
                   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColorEx"));
               }
           }
       }
       // INotifyPropertyChanged event
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {

               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

In this way, you may use the ColorEx property to notify the changes.

2. INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection serve different purpose. 
   ObservableCollection will update the target list when item in the collection changes (for example, added or removed). But if you want to change, say, the color of an item in the collection, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the item.

One thing to keep in mind is that, if you do

`new ObservableCollection<T>()`

the target will not be updated. Because ObservableCollection by itself does not implement notify mechanism.

Comment: You can put an extra four spaces on indenting on the code to make it work with the ordered list. As it is, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah thanks I noticed that. But I don't know if there is any problem with my chrome browser. extra four spaces refuse to work. I put an extra <pre> tag to make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

As Jehof mentioned in the comments, the key here is to create a FruitViewModel to wrap your fruit model.
In that case you will need to tell a specific FruitviewModel to call OnPropertyChanged on one of its properties to work. ("Fruits.Name") will not work.